# Will an Addin Built in outlook 2010 template work on outlook 2013

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, outlook-2010

I have a addin that I have built in Visual Studio 2012 with Outlook 2010 addin template. I want to know whether it will work on Outlook 2013 or not.

I am new to office addins. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried your addin in Outlook 2013? What are the results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, all versions of Office are backward compatible - a COMM addin built for Outlook 2010 should work fine in 2013.